# Reorganize values in 3 arrays based off a unique combination of values in 2 of the arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I have 3 arrays with the data types below:

```
string[] arrID = {"111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "666", "777"};

DateTime[] arrDates = new DateTime[]
{
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 21),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 21),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20)
};

string[] arrTime = {"8:20", "8:40", "8:20", "9:10", "8:20", "9:10", "8:20"};
```

I have added sample elements into the 3 arrays to simulate the types of data we will be having in these arrays.

**Each index number in each of these elements contain values related to one record.**

Example: The values in each of the array with index 3 contains values that make up one record.

I need to put values in these 3 arrays into the following 3 arrays: `arrNEWID`, `arrNEWDate` and `arrNEWTime` based on the following conditions:

- For each unique date and time combination, a separate element needs to be added to each of the arrays.
- If a unique date and time combination has more than one ID, then the IDs need to be separated by a comma.

Expected output in the 3 NEW arrays

```
--------------------------------------------------
| index | arrNEWDate | arrNEWTime | arrNEWID     |
-------------------------------------------------- 
|  0    | 03/20/2015 | 8:20       | 111,333,777  |
|  1    | 03/20/2015 | 8:40       | 222          |
|  2    | 03/20/2015 | 9:10       | 666          |
|  3    | 03/21/2015 | 8:20       | 555          |
|  4    | 03/21/2015 | 9:10       | 444          |
```

Notes:

- The data types on the 3 NEW arrays need to be **string**
- **The input and output need to remain as arrays.** Lists may be created for processing

Here is the code I have used already:

```
string[] arrID = { "111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "666", "777" };

DateTime[] arrDates = new DateTime[]
{
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 21),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 21),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
    new DateTime(2015, 03, 20)
};

string[] arrTime = { "8:20", "8:40", "8:20", "9:10", "8:20", "9:10", "8:20" };

string str_arrNEWID = "";
string str_arrNEWDate = "";
string str_arrNEWTime = "";
string[] arrNEWID = "".Split('~');
string[] arrNEWDate = "".Split('~');
string[] arrNEWTime = "".Split('~');

for (int i = 0; i <= arrID.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    int intExists = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j <= arrNEWDate.GetUpperBound(0); j++)
    {
        //check if date matches for the current index being checked
        if (arrNEWDate[j].ToString() == arrDates[i].Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        {
            //check if time matches for the same index
            if (arrNEWTime[j].ToString() == arrTime[i].ToString())
            {
                //existing record
                intExists = 1;
                arrNEWID[j] = arrNEWID[j] + "," + arrID[i];
                str_arrNEWID = string.Join("~", arrNEWID);
            }
        }

    }

    if (intExists == 0)
    {
        //new record
        str_arrNEWDate = str_arrNEWDate + "~" + arrDates[i].Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") ;
        arrNEWDate = str_arrNEWDate.Split('~');

        str_arrNEWTime = str_arrNEWTime + "~" + arrTime[i].ToString() ;
        arrNEWTime = str_arrNEWTime.Split('~');

        str_arrNEWID = str_arrNEWID + "~" + arrID[i];
        arrNEWID = str_arrNEWID.Split('~');
    }
}
```

**The main challenge is that the compiler that needs to be used to compile this code doesn't support the lambda operator (=>)**

I need to know:

1. If there is a way to do it so that I don't have to use the temporary string variables and split function to refresh the arrays each time
2. If there is any way to get rid of the multiple loops

Comment: What have you tried? What did that code do? How was that different from what you expected or wanted it to do? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: I have added these details. thanks for ur time :)

Comment: Question has been updated. Please remove or explain down votes

Answer (score 0):

arrays make everything more difficult.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string[] arrID = { "111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "666", "777" };

            DateTime[] arrDates = new DateTime[]
            {
                new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
                new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
                new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
                new DateTime(2015, 03, 21),
                new DateTime(2015, 03, 21),
                new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
                new DateTime(2015, 03, 20)
            };

            string[] arrTime = { "8:20", "8:40", "8:20", "9:10", "8:20", "9:10", "8:20" };

            int i = -1;
            int index = 0;
            List<ewansObject> l2 = arrID.Select(o => new ewansObject() { date = arrDates[++i].ToString(), time = arrTime[i], id = arrID[i] }).GroupBy(k => k.date + k.time).Select(o => new ewansObject() { index = index++.ToString(), date = o.First().date, time = o.First().time, id = String.Join(",", o.Select(x => x.id)) }).ToList(); ;

            string[] arrNEWID = l2.Select(x => x.id).ToArray();
            string[] arrNEWDate = l2.Select(x => x.date).ToArray();
            string[] arrNEWTime = l2.Select(x => x.time).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", arrNEWID));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", arrNEWDate));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", arrNEWTime));
        }

        public class ewansObject
        {
            public string index;
            public string date;
            public string time;
            public string id;
        }
    }
}
```

maybe I should change my name to homework4points

Comment: thanks. however, would it be possible to do this without using the lambda operator?

Answer (score 0):

The kind of processing you are looking for is very easily handled by the LINQ features in .NET. In particular, LINQ includes the very handy `group...by` and `orderby` which are directly applicable to your scenario. Unfortunately, the normal LINQ syntax also relies heavily on lambda syntax, which you say you cannot use.

However, note that the lambda syntax is just a "syntactic sugar", i.e. a way of expressing to the compiler something you could write yourself just in a more verbose way. In particular, the lambda syntax as used here generates anonymous methods, which you can of course just write as named methods.

Anonymous methods also allow "capturing" of variables, but in your scenario we can avoid needing to capture any variables by doing two things:

1. Put the data in class fields, where the named method can access them
2. Use the `Enumerable.Select()` overload that passes an index to the selector method, so that the named method can correlated the source items with the elements in the other two arrays that relate to each one

Likewise, while anonymous types would be handy here, effective use of those relies on anonymous methods and inferring types of the method parameters for those anonymous methods. In lieu of that, the `Tuple` class will serve just as well.

Putting all that together, we get something that looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static readonly string[] arrID = { "111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "666", "777" };

    static readonly DateTime[] arrDates = new DateTime[]
    {
        new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
        new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
        new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
        new DateTime(2015, 03, 21),
        new DateTime(2015, 03, 21),
        new DateTime(2015, 03, 20),
        new DateTime(2015, 03, 20)
    };

    static readonly string[] arrTime = { "8:20", "8:40", "8:20", "9:10", "8:20", "9:10", "8:20" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Generate intermediate query with grouped, ordered data
        Tuple<DateTime, string>[] q = arrID.Select(CreateRecord)
            .GroupBy(GetKey)
            .OrderBy(GetGroupKey)
            .Select(FlattenGroup)
            .ToArray();

        // Final output arrays here
        string[] str_arrNEWDate = new string[q.Length],
            str_arrNEWTime = new string[q.Length],
            str_arrNEWID = new string[q.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
        {
            str_arrNEWDate[i] = q[i].Item1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            str_arrNEWTime[i] = q[i].Item1.ToString("HH:mm");
            str_arrNEWID[i] = q[i].Item2;

            // Diagnostic for demonstration purposes
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", q[i].Item1, q[i].Item2);
        }
    }

    private static Tuple<DateTime, string> CreateRecord(string id, int index)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(arrDates[index] + TimeSpan.Parse(arrTime[index]), id);
    }

    private static DateTime GetKey(Tuple<DateTime, string> record)
    {
        return record.Item1;
    }

    private static DateTime GetGroupKey(IGrouping<DateTime, Tuple<DateTime, string>> group)
    {
        return group.Key;
    }

    private static Tuple<DateTime, string> FlattenGroup(IGrouping<DateTime, Tuple<DateTime, string>> group)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(group.Key, string.Join(",", group.Select(GetId)));
    }

    private static string GetId(Tuple<DateTime, string> record)
    {
        return record.Item2;
    }
}
```

As you can see, everywhere that you would normally write a lambda expression, in the above instead we just have a regular `static` method to do the work. Note that if you were dealing with a non-`static` class and the method needed to access instance members, the methods can simply be made non-`static` instead.

Delegate type inference takes care of constructing the delegate instances that need to be passed to the LINQ methods.

**Note:** while you don't say so explicitly in your question, the nature of the specifications strongly hints that this is homework. As such, you should make very sure you take the time to actually *understand* the above code example. Otherwise you have learned nothing, wasting your time in the class. Please feel free to ask questions here about my answer, and of course you should feel comfortable asking your teacher to help you understand both the original assignment and this answer.